# Should edits trying to improve the content of an answer be approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

Should edits attempting to improve the content of an answer be approved?

For example, I reviewed [this edit on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1853516).

I'd say I'd approve it, but I was wondering if the asker of the question would get the option to approve/reject the edit himself? Is it actually up to me to decide whether or not to approve such an edit?

Comment: A totally new user changes the source code in a highly upvoted answer of a high rep user. Ahem no! Or are you an expert in the matter and did verify the changes?

Comment: It depends - do you know enough about the subject matter to make a judgement on whether this is in fact an improvement? If you don't, keep away.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep away next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### When to approve?

- If there are some spelling mistakes in code/other text.
- If grammar is improved (but doesn't change the meaning)
- If broken links are fixed.

#### When to reject?

- If it changes main code.
- If it adds additional code. (Though it depends sometimes.)
- If it adds another solution.
- If edit summary fails to explain diffs I observe.

#### When to skip?

- If you are not aware of the subject (i.e. tag)
- If you can't judge what to do (obviously!)

<sup>(PS: This is what I do while reviewing.)</sup>

Comment: `"when to reject" += "If edit summary fails to explain diffs I observe"` (not applicable for this particular case, with [pretty detailed and easy to read summary](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1853516 "'I've modified your original to provide...'"), but as a general guideline makes a good sense doesn't it?)

Comment: @gnat - Fair enough. Hope you edit it. :)

Comment: "If it changes main code"?  Doesn't that include corrections to main code when it's wrong?

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I've used this answer as a template for [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175298/clear-rules-on-reviewing-edits)